# Change JavaScript version while debugging

Tags: javascript, debugging, backwards-compatibility

I would like to test a website with an older version of JavaScript to make sure that we are not using any new methods or plugins that breaks in old browsers. Is there any way whether to emulate or to force the browser to use older javascript versions such as the ones here: [JavaScript Version History](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaScript#Version_history)

Comment: The only solution I know of is to test using multiple browsers using services such as [cross browser testing](https://crossbrowsertesting.com/). I have no affiliation with CBT. As this answer is essentially looking for a tool recommendation, it is technically [off-topic (#4)](/help/on-topic).

Comment: Off-topic, so my suggestion goes in a comment https://www.browserstack.com/ You can also use https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/tools/vms/ for IE

Comment: I was actually hoping for an answer that does not involve online services or tools, but if it can only be done through those, I'd be happy to close the question. Thank you for the recommendations though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From experience this gets messy. You are best using free software such as https://www.virtualbox.org/ which allows you to setup up an actual old machine running an old browser (as many as the test system can take).
That way you replicate the precise test environment.
You should be able to get various old OS machine installs cheaply as they have no value.